# Rails find_by_sql returning array with empty object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I am using `find_by_sql` to do a query on my Conversationalist model using Postgres as the DB server:

```
Conversationalist.find_by_sql(['
  SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT * FROM conversationalists
    WHERE conversable_id = ? AND conversable_type = ?
  ) t1 
  LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT * FROM conversationalists 
    WHERE conversable_id = ? AND conversable_type = ?
  ) t2 
  ON t1.chat_id = t2.chat_id',
  recipient_id, recipient_type, sender_id, sender_type])
```

It works fine if there is a result. But if there is no result then I get an array with an empty `Conversationalist` object: `[#<Conversationalist id: nil, conversable_type: nil...>]`

Here is what I get as a result doing a direct query on the DB:

[image]

What I am expecting is an empty array since no rows should be returned but instead I get a result. How would I get an empty array if no results are returned?

**ADDITIONAL CONTEXT**

What I am trying to do is essentially a chat. When someone messages another user, the code above first checks to see if those two people are already chatting. If they are the message gets added to the chat. If not, a new Chat gets created and the message gets added:

```
class MessagesController < ApplicationController
  def create
    message = new_message
    conversation = already_conversing?
    if conversation.empty? || conversation.first.id.nil?
      chat = Chat.new
      chat.messages << message
      chat.conversationalists << sender
      chat.conversationalists << recipient
      chat.save!
    else
      chat = Chat.find(conversation.first.chat_id)
      chat.messages << message
    end
    head :ok
  end

  private

  def new_message
    Message.new(
      sender_id: params[:sender_id], 
      sender_type: params[:sender_type],
      recipient_id: params[:recipient_id],
      recipient_type: params[:recipient_type],
      message: params[:message] 
    )
  end

  def already_conversing?
    Conversationalist.conversing?(
      params[:recipient_id], 
      params[:recipient_type], 
      params[:sender_id], 
      params[:sender_type]
    )
  end
end
```

The Model:

```
class Conversationalist < ApplicationRecord
  def self.conversing?(recipient_id, recipient_type, sender_id, sender_type)
    Conversationalist.find_by_sql(['
      SELECT * FROM (
        SELECT * FROM conversationalists
        WHERE conversable_id = ? AND conversable_type = ?
      ) t1 
      LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT * FROM conversationalists 
        WHERE conversable_id = ? AND conversable_type = ?
      ) t2 
      ON t1.chat_id = t2.chat_id',
      recipient_id, recipient_type, sender_id, sender_type])
  end
end
```

Comment: I don't understand your usage here. You are enclosing the whole think in an array. Can you try just calling the `find_by_sql('Select... ')` without the enclosing array or the parameters at the end?

Comment: I need the array to bind the parameters (recipient_id, recipient_type...)(https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Querying.html). Without the array you would get an error: "wrong number of arguments (given 5, expected 1..2)"

Comment: Here is how I would troubleshoot this: I would run this in a SQL query in your DB native application i.e. I use Postgres so I would run just the query in `psql` to see the result. You also don't say what DB you are using.

Comment: I see what you mean about the parameters, I have not used `find_by_sql` where I needed to pass parameters so that threw me for a second. It feels like your query is returning some sort of an empty row instead of nil. That's why I'd run it in `psql` to see what you get. Also it's hard to visualize because we don't know your entire data structure. Can you post a full `inspect` of the empty object?

Comment: I edited the question to include the results of using psql. I get 0 rows returned, but for whatever reason it creates an empty object and adds it to the array. This might the expected behavior, to say "if no results return an empty object of the requesting model" but I can't find something saying as much in the documentation so I figured I try here.

Comment: Weird, I can test it on one of my projects and 0 rows always gives an empty array like you are expecting. I thought that is the expected behavior too because that is what I've always gotten. Can you show some of the context of the code you originally posted? Is it doing the same thing on the Rails console?

Comment: Thats what I expected as well. It may be a bug but I figure I check first. I added additional context.

Comment: That helps. And if you run just the original `find_by_sql` query on the Rails console it still returns an empty object?

Comment: I got it! In the first inner select statement, if there is any match at all then it will return a result with an empty object even if there are no results in the overall query. Thanks for you help! Your comments helped get me there.

Comment: I wonder if that is because you are also doing a left join on the SAME table so it's really a self join?

Comment: Also you can Answer your own question below so that it helps others running into the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I was able to figure it out with the help of @Beartech from the comments above. Essentially the issue was happening because of the LEFT JOIN. If there are any results in `t1` then Rails returns an array with an empty object. Similarly, if it was a RIGHT JOIN and `t2` had a result, Rails would do the same. So the fix, in order to get an empty array, is to change the join to an INNER JOIN:

```
Conversationalist.find_by_sql(['
  SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT * FROM conversationalists
    WHERE conversable_id = ? AND conversable_type = ?
  ) t1 
  INNER JOIN (
    SELECT * FROM conversationalists 
    WHERE conversable_id = ? AND conversable_type = ?
  ) t2 
  ON t1.chat_id = t2.chat_id',
  recipient_id, recipient_type, sender_id, sender_type])
```